# How can angularJS directive access arguments passed in from HTML?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an angularJS app.

Here is what's in my HTML template:

```
LoremIpsum: <a-directive aX="99">
```

Here is my directive in my `app.js` file:

```
app.directive('aDirective',function(){
    return {
        restrict:'E',
        scope: {
            aX: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log('aX = ', scope.aX);
            if (scope.aX == 'foo') 
                scope.contentUrl = 'foo.html';
            else
                scope.contentUrl = 'bar.html';

        },
        template: '<div ng-include="contentUrl"></div>'
    };
});
```

When I run this code, the console.log line shows that thevalue of `aX` is undefined. Why? How do I make sure it gets the value 99 that is being passed in?

Comment: I think you want to define a in the directive's scope as `a: '@'`

Comment: Brad, that didn't help. In fact when I changed `'='` to `'@'`, `a` was still undefined. However, previously, although its value was undefined, at least there was a `skope.a`. Now there is no `a` attached to skope.

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: try attrs.a instead of scope.a

Comment: Google Chrome on Mac OSX.

Comment: Works OK in [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/736hnjrp/).

Comment: georgeawg, How can you see what console.log produces in the JSFiddle? I don't see the value 99 in your output.

Comment: ctrl-shift-j opens the JavaScript console on my browser (Chrome).

Comment: sdfacre, that worked! Except it only works if the name of the variable is lower case. If I change `a` to `aX`, it shows up in the directive as `attrs.ax`. Very weird.

Comment: @Saquib Ali, did you follow the right naming convention in HTML? <a-directive a-x="99">? it should work as expected, attrs.aX.

Comment: @sdfacre. No I didn't! Thanks for pointing that out. I thought that naming convention applied only to the directive name, not to the attributes as well. Thank you.